# Security errors with printer

Tags: nessus, printers

I ran a security scan using the home version of Nessus by following a post on LifeHacker, and I was told that my printer had two security errors:

1. OpenSSL 'ChangeCipherSpec' MiTM Vulnerability
2. SNMP Agent Default Community Name (public)

Seeing as this is a network printer, I cannot set up advanced systems, and turning off SNMP (or changing any settings) is no longer an option in its online config menu.

I am a total security noob, so I thought I would ask this community whether this endangers my home network, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Please tell us how the printer is or might be reachable from any untrusted network, including the Internet. In particular, as seen from the Internet, is the printer squarely behind a firewall?

Comment: Are we talking about your *home* network or your workplace?

Comment: @Hollowproc one would hope that an employee isn't running Nessus at work after reading a Lifehacker article, but it is good to check this assumption ...

Comment: @schroeder yea I think we've all been burned by assumptions

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, This is a home network. I just saw those warning and whated to check with this community

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot disable SNMP protocol can you at least rename the community string and give it a strong password? If so that should suffice.
Regarding the OpenSSL vulnerability that would have to be resolved by the vendor with a firmware update. See if one is available.